# Working with Threads - UbuntuTouch/QML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, ubuntu, qml

I'm taking my first steps writing an QML/javascript application for Ubuntu touch using qt creator.

Currently there i dont think there's too much documentation on this topic.

Can anyone point me out a good/clean way to work on multiple threads in this circumstance?

Comment: Why do you need multithreading control for your UI? What's your final purpose? As mentioned by @Deadron below, if you need to perform really heavy tasks you can use a `WorkerScript`, but it would be an advanced feature; not something for one who's "taking his first steps" in QML.

Comment: @_TheHuge_ I´m not new to mobile development in general and know that the last thing i wanna do is blocking the ui thread with non ui related code i`m running. For now its a metronome i want to do that ticks reliable in certain amounts of time. I dont know if the worker is the thing for that but running on main thread would mean goodbye responsive ui. Except that: Why do i have to explain myself about my intensions!? (Dont need an answer for this one!)

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions seemed annoying. My point is this: QML is a language for UI, and you should use it just to define your application UI. Therefore there is no need (except for few peculiar cases) to manage threads for doing non-UI related tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QML is not really designed with the intention of working within more than one thread. The origional intention was that any threading should be handled by the layer existing in C++. However, if you do really need acces to threads to perform things like calculations, and you are unable/unwilling to write code at the C++ level, there is the WorkerScript QML element that may be able to provide the funcionality you want.

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-workerscript.html

Its worth note that depending on what you are trying to do this may or may not be entirely appropriate to use.